# InSpec should_be_listening Test Fails When Port is Open

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, inspec

**Environment**

chefdk 1.3.40

berks 5.6.4

kitchen 1.16.0

vagrant 1.9.3

After a 'kitchen login', we can see that port 80 has been opened

```
sudo iptables-save | grep 80
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

However, when running 'kitchen verify' the test fails:

```
PORT 80
[MAJR]  should be listening
expected 'Port 80.listening?' to return true, got false
```

Here is the Inspec test:

```
describe port(80) do
  it { should be_listening }
end
```

Comment: And is an application actually listening to port 80? Because you're just showing the iptables rules (or is the magic in the `conntrack` part)? Try `netstat -ntl`, as this is IIRC what Inspec calls.

Comment: No, an application is not (yet) listening. We are trying to test-drive this and that part of the recipe is still being written.

netstat -ntl
tcp    0    0    0.0.0.0:80    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN

Comment: @StephenKing Adding the chef_nginx recipe made this test pass. If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the commands provided, there is no indication that any program is actually listening to port 80. The `iptables-save` output only shows a firewall rule that permits incoming connections.

InSpec itself calls [`netstat -tulpen`](https://github.com/chef/inspec/blob/c70824d0c840199bdbaee31dc5353e5673e94d8a/lib/resources/port.rb#L269) to gather information about listening sockets. You might want to use this to verify manually.